# Wireshark is not capturing traffic through http://localhost:8888

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, wireshark

Currently, my wireshark can capture traffic from http://localhost (traffic that is on port 80) but it won't capture traffic on localhost:8888

Is there any extra configuration/software that I need for wireshark to capture traffic of localhost on this port? I'm running Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 1):

In preferences you can set a list of ports that wireshark recognizes as http.

Comment: Yes.  What he probably means by "won't capture traffic on localhost:8888" is "isn't showing HTTP traffic to or from localhost:8888", which would, by default, happen because Wireshark doesn't think of port 8888 as an HTTP port.  A `PF_PACKET` socket bound to the `lo` device, which is what libpcap uses to capture on the loopback device, will see all loopback traffic, regardless of the port, unless you've explicitly specified a capture filter that discards traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Try 127.0.0.1:8888 instead, I am at school so I can't test this at the moment but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

What capture and display filters are you using?

Have you tried connecting using your local IP address instead of the loopback interface? That is, try http://192.168.xxx.xxx/ or whatever your local IP is.